Как подключить клиента к серверу в глобальной сети?
Написал простенькие программы клиента и сервера. При локальном соединении все ок. Стоит указать клиенту в socket->connectToHost(...); свой глобальный ip адрес, сокет выдает ошибку "Connection refused.". Сервер слушает QHostAddress::Any. Есть какие отличия при попытке соединения по локальному и глобальному ip-шнику? В качестве сервера использую QTcpServer, сокет QTcpSocket. ip адрес белый.
UPD:
При подключении клиента с другой машины и с другим роутером выводит "Network operation timed out"
server.cpp
Server::Server()
{
    if(listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1234)) {
        qDebug() << "start";
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "ne start";
    }
}

Обработка подключения клиента:
void Server::incomingConnection(qintptr handle)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket;
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(handle);
    connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &Server::slotReadyRead);
    connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, this, &Server::socketDisconnected);
    sockets.push_back(socket);
    qDebug() << "client connected" << handle;
}

client.cpp
Подключение сокета к серверу
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent),
      socket(new QTcpSocket(this))
{
    connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &Widget::slotReadyRead);
    connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::disconnected, socket, &QTcpSocket::deleteLater);
    connect(socket, &QTcpSocket::errorOccurred, this, &Widget::socketError);

    socket->connectToHost("178.65.126.214", 1234);
    socket->waitForConnected();
}

так же прилагаю схему сети(вроде все просто и понятно)


На роутере сервера необходимо настроить NAT чтобы он при получении из интернета пакетов на порт 1234 перенаправлял их на сервер по локальному IP. И еще про файрвол на самом сервере тоже не забыть и добавить там разрашение для приема соединений.

Порты могут быть закрыты и/или запрещены входящие соединения у провайдера, на роутере не настроен проброс портов или DMZ, и/или блокироваться соединения firewall-ом сервера. Это всё можно обойти если использовать посредников, например zerotier.

Благодаря подсказке из комментариев, я настроил проброс портов в меню роутера с нужного порта на нужный локальный ip и все заработало. У моего роутера это выглядит вот так:


Дополню вопрос ответом из своего опыта.
Потребовалось настроить проброску портов в роутере, но также пришлось дополнительно указывать IP сетевой карты, которая использовалась для целевой виртуальной машины, т.к. сервер крутился на виртуалке.

